# how to use huffman algorithm in steganography?

Tags: huffman-code, steganography

i have used Huffman coding on may data and then embedding them into an image. in extraction part for Huffman algorithm i need some information (Huffman table) about Huffman like alpha and their probability to create Huffman dictionary.
 i want to know how to transform them. is there anyway except inserting alpha and probability separately in to image pixel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way of storing Huffman tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759707/efficient-way-of-storing-huffman-tree)